# is there is any way to set height and width of font Awesome Icon to the full width and height of its parent container?

Tags: css, height, width, font-awesome

I want to set the height and width of the Font Awesome icon to the full width and height of its parent container.

**CSS**

```
.icon-container {
width:30px;
height:30px;
}
.fa-facebook-square {
//what should be here
//font-size is not working properly in this scenario
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="icon-container">
 <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave an autowidth class to  element after its own classes. Then give display inline-block to it and add with and height equal to 100% to take the parent's width and height.

```css
.icon-container {
width:60px;
height:60px;
}
.icon-container .autowidth {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-container">
 <i class="fab fa-facebook-square autowidth"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: What is that script came from? I have noticed that this is the main reason for this attitude to work

Answer (score 0):

Check this ->
      https://jsfiddle.net/2na108rc/1/

```
 <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>


.fa-facebook-square {
   font-size: 200px;
   font-weight: 900;
 }
```

Comment: I want to set the width and height of the icon to the full width and height of its parent container.